# consistent prediction results in Weka despite different seeds value

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, weka

I am using Weka 3.8.3 multilayer perceptron on Iris dataset. I have 75 training instances and 75 test instances. The thing is no matter how I change the 'seed' parameter, it does not affect the accuracy that much. It's almost always the stats below. Is seed used to randomly initialize the weight? Could someone please help to explain why it behaves this way? Many thanks.

```
=== Summary ===

 Correctly Classified Instances          70               93.3333 %
 Incorrectly Classified Instances         5                6.6667 %
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing (Training and test 50% percentage split using the radio button) and got 72 and 3 with a random seed for XVal / % Split of 1.

When I change the random seed to 777 (or 666 or 54321) I get 73 and 2, which is a different result, so I can't replicate what you are seeing.

With a random seed of 0 I get 71 and 4.

Comment: Thanks for your help. With 0 or 777,666 I got 70 and 5 in all the cases.. Not sure what I did wrong.. Is there a way that we could set the initial weights, like set them all to 0 or 0.1?  I googled but could not find a solution

Comment: Not sure which weights are are thinking about.  By default, each instance gets a weight of 1.  If you have unequal classes (say, 10,000 of class A and 100 of class B) you might want to use the Class Balancer filter (a supervised instance filter) to give equal weight to the two classes. The AdaBoostM1 (meta classifier) weights incorrect instances more heavily over successive iterations in order to improve their prediction.  So there are lots of potential weights.